# What Linux software can I use to explore entropy of a file?

Tags: binary-analysis

I've heard of [tools](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=158) that could be used to graph entropy of a file. Is there a graphical Linux program that I could use for this job that would let me conveniently explore which blocks of a file have certain entropy patterns that could suggest compressed or encrypted data?

Comment: What definition of entropy are you interested in, e.g. binary Shannon entropy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the #entropy command [radare2](http://rada.re). [binwalk](http://binwalk.org) can calculate entropy, too.

### Radare2

From the manual page of Radare2:

```
 #[hash]     Calculates the sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512, par, xor,
             xorpair, hamdist, mod255, crc16, crc32, md4, md5, entropy of
             the current block from the selected seek
```

So, using this command is as follow:

```
$ radare2 /bin/ls
[0x00404890]> #entropy
5.338618
```

### Binwalk

If you get binwalk from the [original Github project](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk), you will also grad a few [Python modules](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/tree/master/src/binwalk/modules), one of these is computing the [entropy of the analyzed file](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk/blob/master/src/binwalk/modules/entropy.py).

Get these modules and run it on your file.

Comment: Those are both good suggestions, but I'd add that there is great insight to be gained in writing your own tools.

Comment: commands: `radare2 -q -c '#entropy' file` and `binwalk -E file`

Answer (score 8):

[Detect It Easy](http://ntinfo.biz/index.php/detect-it-easy) can do it:

[image: Entropy]

There is version for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ent`: https://www.fourmilab.ch/random/ to run statistical tests checking for randomness.

```
$ cat 1-gb-file.img | ent
Entropy = 7.999998 bits per byte.

Optimum compression would reduce the size
of this 100000000 byte file by 0 percent.

Chi square distribution for 100000000 samples is 249.38, and randomly
would exceed this value 58.75 percent of the times.

Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 127.4928 (127.5 = random).
Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.141514686 (error 0.00 percent).
Serial correlation coefficient is -0.000094 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
```